# Can I implement this search phrase as a Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the following search phrase in a text input box

```
"phrase one" "phrase two" one two
```

I want the search phrase sent to the server in the following format

```
|phrase one|phrase two|one|two
```

I can use regex to replace `|` at the start and end of the search string but am struggling to complete the rest.

In english this would be search for

```
phrase one OR phrase two OR one OR two
```

The regex would be something like

```
replace " with |
replace space with | for a phrase not in quotes ("")
```

I am using Javascript.

Comment: `Can I implement this search phrase as a Javascript regular expression` - yes you can - good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(?:"[^"]+"|\w+)
```

Explaining:

```
(?:             # one of the alternations
    "           # starting with quotes
    [^"]+       # a sequence of not quotes
    "           # the closing quotes
|               # OR
    \w+         # a word sequence
)               #
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/qZ9fZ3/1)

```js
var string = '"phrase one" "phrase two" one two'; // textbox input

var answer = ''; // starts empty


string.replace(/(?:"[^"]+"|\w+)/g, function (match) {

  answer += '|' + match.match(/[^"]+/)[0];
  // foreach match add one pipe '|' and the value without quotes to answer

});

answer = answer.slice(1);

document.write(answer); // the message you want send to server
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm just seeing this now. can you explain how it works ?

Comment: @alanoreilly. Let me know if you didn't understand something.

Comment: is it possible to remove the first pipe character from the answer variable so instead of '|phrase one|phrase two|one|two' it becomes 'phrase one|phrase two|one|two'

Comment: @alanoreilly. You can add this line `answer = answer.slice(1)` at the end. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks..i moved the pipe to the end and did another regex of answer = answer.replace(/[|]$/,'');